# Containing columns in row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I've created three columns which I want to contain inside a row which is then contained inside of a section.

For some reason the three columns will not contain inside of the row correctly, Is there a better method or something that I've missed out in the code to correct this?

```css
.column-1-3 {
  width: 29.666%;
  margin-right: 5.5%;
  float: left;
}

.column-last-child {
  margin-right: 0!important;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 40px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  min-width: 414px;
  margin: auto;
}

.post {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  padding: 50px;
}

.video-post {
  background: #000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column-1-3">
      <div class="video-post"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-1-3">
      <div class="video-post"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-1-3 column-last-child">
      <div class="video-post"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are facing ?

Comment: The code is working fine. What do you need help with?

Comment: You need to apply a float clearing on the container, that's why the container has 0 height. Lately you will discard float and find a lot useful display: flexbox instead of using odd margin values

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` on row, and remove `float` property from `column-1-3`:

```css
.column-1-3 {
  width: 30%;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 40px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  min-width: 414px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.post {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  padding: 50px;
}

.video-post {
  background: #000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column-1-3">
      <div class="video-post"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-1-3">
      <div class="video-post"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-1-3">
      <div class="video-post"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You also dont need to set `margin`s with `flex`. Just keep `width: 30%` on columns and use `justify-content: space-between;` on rows.

Comment: You also dont need to set margins with flex. Just keep 30% width of columns and use justify-content: space-between; on row

Comment: Perfect, saved me a lot of time. Thanks again.